# Any particular reason why CronTriggerFactoryBean doesn't support setting endTime in Spring Boot with Quartz?

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

We have a use case where we need to support creating cron triggers with an optional end time.
Spring's CronTriggerFactoryBean does not expose a setter for the underlying CronTriggerImpl's endTime property.
Setting the endTime on the generated CronTriggerImpl itself seems to be working as expected, but I was wondering if there's a particular reason why CronTriggerFactoryBean does not expose a setter for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CronScheduleBuilder` instead of `CronTriggerFactoryBean` :

```java
MutableTrigger mutableTrigger = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("your cron expression...").build();
mutableTrigger.setEndTime(yourEndDate);
```